# Who are the people that the Beast Titan turned into titans?

Tags: attack-on-titan

In season 3 part 2 episode 13, we see the Beast Titan for the second time in the anime. He suddenly appears with an army of titans who transform with him but who are these people? The citizens of Ragako? The rest of the people that traveled with him to Paradise Island?

Comment: Just saying that Zeke, Bertolt, Annie, Reiner, and Pieck are the only Marleyans that made it all the way to the Walls in Paradis. They could be citizens from other remote villages turned into Titans by Zeke as he could only control Titans he created.

Comment: AH-HA I knew it.  Why would titan shifters need soldiers to guard them?

Comment: What soldiers? Which titan shifters are you referring to?

Comment: Marleyan soldiers the comes that you said:  Zeke, Bertolt, Annie, Reiner, and Pieck

Comment: It seems like there's a lot of information you still don't know (regarding the identities of the titan shifters). I suggest reading the manga from where the anime finished as anything beyond would be spoilers.

Comment: What do you mean?  They all came to paradise.

Answer (score 1):

The new titans inside wall Rose are the villagers of [Ragako](https://attackontitan.fandom.com/wiki/Ragako). The wiki linked makes this explicit, although the information comes from the Unnamed Final Arc.

> According to Zeke, after having infiltrated Wall Rose, himself, Pieck, and a small group of Marleyan soldiers locate Ragako and choose to target it. The soldiers release a gas diffused with Zeke's spinal fluid and the wind quickly blows it as a fog over the village. Once the subjects of Ymir that inhabit the village inhale this gas, they are paralyzed and etched with a coordinate. Zeke screams, making the paths transform the villagers and allowing him to impose his will on their Pure Titans due to their connection with his Beast Titan.[1](https://attackontitan.fandom.com/wiki/Ragako)

In the anime, this is more implied than spelled out. There are a number of pieces of evidence, the most significant of which are; the village is empty, but the horses remain. The village is destroyed, but no blood or bodies are found. And that the trapped [Titan](https://attackontitan.fandom.com/wiki/Ms._Springer) looks like Connie's mother.

[image: Mrs Springer - Human][image: Mrs Springer - Titan]

Comment: Weren't the Ragako villagers those who attacked Nanaba's group in the tower they took refuge in?

Comment: @W.Are The implication in the Anime, and the direct references from the Manga suggest both groups are the Ragako villagers. How many people live in a village inside the walls isn't clear. But there could easily be enough in a single village to account for all the Pure Titan's seen during the Clash of the Titans Arc.

Comment: I see. But I seem to have missed these references. Because as far as I recall, I cannot remember the manga implying that the Ragako villagers where also those who attacked Shinganshina during the Clash of the Titans arc. Although, I am not dismissing this possibility.

Comment: @W.Are my bad. I had the wall name incorrect. Ragako villiagers are all inside Wall Rose. They didn't attach  Shiganshina because they were all human at the time. [Clash of Titan](https://attackontitan.fandom.com/wiki/Story_Arcs) arc starts with introduction of the Beast Titan, inside the 2nd wall.

Comment: It is possible that Zeke could have saved some for later. Thank you for your answer. Also, @W.Are these are the soldiers  I was talking about in the other question, and yes, they are the same group. One of the titans that attacked the tower looked like Connie's dad.